# Unity 2D make item move around player in a cricle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, 2d, game-development

So what I want is to move an item around the player in a circle but the item is moving along the circle depending on the mouse position. Im trying to do this as a sort of item equip thing and I can't get it to work.

What I have so far is the item moving in a circle around the player but not along the circle depending on the mouse position.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform target;

public SpriteRenderer renderer;
public float circleRadius = 1f;
public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
public float elevationOffset = 0f;

Vector2 positionOffset;
float angle;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    positionOffset.Set(
        Mathf.Cos(angle) * circleRadius,
        Mathf.Sin(angle) * circleRadius
    );

    transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x + positionOffset.x, target.position.y + positionOffset.y);
    angle += Time.fixedDeltaTime * rotationSpeed;
}
```

}

Comment: So make the target the world point of the mouse cursor?

Comment: Tried that but that just seemd to place the item at a position outside of the cameras view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that `target` is the "player" then we can:

1. Get the mouse position, as a world co-ordinate
2. Normalise the difference between the mouse and the player, times radius
3. Position the item along that normalised direction

```cs
private void Update ( )
{
    var worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( Input.mousePosition );
    var positionOnCircle = (worldPosition - target.position).normalized * circleRadius;
    transform.position = target.position + positionOnCircle;
}
```